# A little gap after <br/> tag

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I have a paragraph with two lines separated by a line break < br/ > tag. How do I insert a small gap between the first line and the second?

I want to do this without adding new markup so I don't have to edit every page on my site.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the <p>'s have any class or identifier on them other than just `p`? You could use CSS `line-height`.

Comment: try adding a margin, `margin-top{0.8em;}`, or if you want each line in the paragraph be more spaced out use `line-height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `<br/>` tag with css and go from there. For example:

```
br{
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Although, this will target ALL br tags. Without knowing your code its hard to get more specific than that, maybe `p + br { ... }`